# Object not found error when attempting to use get() function

Tags: r

I'm writing a short loop to read in a number of SAS files and save them as R files.  The SAS and R file names need to be different, and the R variable name is different to the R file name. I am storing these names in character vectors.

I've successfully used `assign()` to load the SAS file and give it a different variable name within R.  However when I go to save it using get I receive a "object not found" error.

```r
SAS_file_names <- c('SAS1','SASa')
R_file_names <- c('R1','Ra')
R_variable_names <- c('Arr1','Arra')

for (i in 1:length(SAS_file_names)){
    SASfilename <- fullFileNameSAS(SAS_file_names[i])
    Rfilename <- fullFileNameR(R_file_names[i])

    assign(R_variable_names[i],tbl_df(read_sas(paste0(SASdata_dir, SASfilename))))
    save(get(R_variable_names[i), file = paste0(Rdata_dir, Rfilename))
    #Error: object ‘get(R_variable_names[1])’ not found
    remove(get(R_variable_names[i]))
    #Error: must contain names or character strings
}
```

I've tried running just `get(R_variable_names[1])` in the console and it works fine, returning the object.  However it gives an error when used as an input to a function.

Comment: remove the get around the thing you want to remove. rm/remove take the object name as a string, not as an object. If that still errors use `remove(list = R_variable_names[i])`

Comment: What is the function fullFileNameSAS?

Comment: fullFileNameSAS adds a date suffix and file extension to the file name

Comment: Using list = R_variable_names[i] instead of get() works for both save() and remove()

Comment: Not sure how to accept an answer